# Is There a Difference in Methods of Command Execution in a Subshell?

Tags: bash, syntax

I wonder if there is a significant difference of calling sub shell via `$(...)` or `` `...` ``?

For example:

```
a=$(ls -la /tmp | grep vox-*)
```

And:

```
a=`ls -la /tmp | grep vox-*`
```

The result will be the completely the same, but I want to know why there are two different methods, what the difference is, and which one I should use.

Comment: Actually, neither of these will work because you have spaces around the `=`. In the shell, spaces are forbidden around the `=` when doing an assignment, but required when doing a test (like `if [ "$a" = "$b" ]; then`).

Comment: Yes, you completely right, i just used spaces around "=" to make the expression clearly readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backsticks and `$(...)` are identical in terms of functionality. However I prefer the second approach

- `$(...)` can be easily nested
- readability, `$(...)` is more "bashish"
- consistency, as a similar syntax, `$((...))`, is for expressions

See also [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) that has other arguments.

Comment: `$( )` is not bashish or à bashism, it was introduced by ksh and is POSIX.